# Function is not working with create image

Tags: php

Can we call function in imagestring with using text argument?

```
imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  **$graph->createGraph()**, $text_color)
```

OR

Another way to create image of an function output as data?

Comment: Well, if that function call returns a string you obviously can according to the ``imagestring()`` documentation. So what is your _real_ question here?

Comment: That argument has to be a string of text. It seems unlikely that something called `createGraph` would return text.

Comment: I'm trying to create image using imagestring() while its text argument take an function output

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: How does this address his question? He asked if you can call a function instead of providing a simple text string.